# Length of a line in an isosceles triangle. (mind boggling )

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles

[image]

In an isosceles $\triangle ABC$, side $AB$ and $AC$ are equal in length. There exists a point $D$ on the side $AB$. $\angle BAC$ is $\theta$. The side $AD$ is $2$ units smaller than $AC$. What is the generalized formula to calculate the side $CD$?

Comment: I have tried this thing. I think that the formula would require some simple trignometry.

Comment: BD can be anything.

Comment: yes bd can be anything.

Comment: Use the Law of Cosines

Comment: I am asking for a proof in an algebraic form. Well I have also applied the law of cosines

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple application of the cosine rule to the triangle $ACD$

$$CD^2=(a-2)^2+a^2-2a(a-2)\cos\theta$$

Comment: Ok I will verify and confirm it.

Comment: ok thank you this works. good job

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a picture to convince yourself that the length of $BD$ does not depend on $\theta$. You will need to be given more information.